# ios How can i hide default interface(volumn and rewind buttons) of MPNowPlayingInfoCenter when my app is playing audio on background?

Tags: ios

How can i hide default interface,volume and rewind buttons, of MPNowPlayingInfoCenter when my app is playing audio on background? I tried using MPCommandCenter,but it can not achieve my goal